# sharing WPF ControlTemplates

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I'm trying to learn more about WPF. I ran through an online tutorial that created a button and then created a template to be applied to additional buttons. The problem is this template is in the Window.xaml and I can only access the template from within that application. How do I make the template more globablly available? I'm thinking of some way to reference the xaml like you can reference an assembly from a different project or solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "resource dictionaries" which you reference in your App.xaml like this (Expression Blend does it automatically):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

How to reference a resource from another assembly, use pack URI syntax. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/wpf-resource-dictionary-in-a-separate-assembly) covers it as well.