# Load element from external file

Tags: c#, wpf, xamlreader

I want to load a WPF element from an external file. Example I have a file `brush.xaml` like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush>Black</SolidColorBrush>
```

And I want to load this brush in my code:

```
using(FileStream stream = new FileStream("brush.xaml"))
  Brush myBrush = XamlReader.Load(stream) as Brush;
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is right, but in the xaml file use:

```
<SolidColorBrush xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
   #FF0000
</SolidColorBrush>
```

With the hexadecimal format. Anyway, if you have any doubt, you can make a test using [`XamlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading it by parsing XAML. Put these elements in a resource dictionary. You can reference these resources in both XAML and C#.

For more info:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35346/Using-a-Resource-Dictionary-in-WPF

[Accessing ResourceDictionary from WPF UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940879/accessing-resourcedictionary-from-wpf-usercontrol)

Comment: No, i need to load it parsing XAML as I wrote.