# Is it possible to share a ResourceDictionary file between multiple projects?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

If I have a ResourceDictionary in one project, is it possible to create another project that uses resources defined in the first project? Note that both projects are WPF Applications, not ControlLibraries.

Thanks!!

Comment: Duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/wpf-resource-dictionary-in-a-separate-assembly

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, of course that's possible, as long as Project B has a reference to Project A.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Project A;component/YourSubFolder/YourResourceFile.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Then you can just use the Resources defined in YourResourceFile.xaml.

Comment: Oh snap. I'm giving that a try! Thanks!!

Comment: What happens if the projects don't share a reference? In my case I'm using PRISM and declaring styles in the Shell. I'd like to be able to reuse some of the defined colours.

Comment: If the Styles are defined in the Shell, then every object can use them, I think. Since the XAML is loaded into the MainPage at runtime, it also gets access to the global Resources.

Answer (score 13):

I found that I had to reference the assembly itself and not use a project name. I also did not need to use the pack:/// syntax to get this to work.

This answer on the duplicate question specifies the format to use (I can verify that this syntax works in .NET 4.0):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216253/1260563

Specifically (since I always forget the component part thinking it is a folder someone is using):

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="/<YourAssemblyName>;component/<YourReferencedFileHere.xaml>" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

So if you have an assembly Abc.Def.dll and a file in that DLL called Xyz.xaml at the root level you would use:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="/Abc.Def;component/Xyz.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Note: Resharper 7 pointed out that I had to reference the assembly itself.

Comment: Thank you for giving specific examples and pointing out the need for the component part of the path. This helped more than  the half-dozen other solutions I've stumbled across.