# How to style a XAML window with a ResourceDictionary that exist in a DLL?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dll, styles, resourcedictionary

Hi I am trying to create a reusable XAML Window in a DLL.

I have placed in the Themes folder a new ResourceDictionary (I even merged it in the Generic.xaml), but when I try to use its styles in the window, I get an error message that the style doesn't exist:

```
<Window Style="{StaticResource ModalWindowStyle}" >
    <!-- I have also the following -->
    <Window.Resources>    
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

I get an exception that this styles don't exist, they are both declared in that ResourceDictionary which is in the Themes folder.

Comment: Did you reference the resource dictionary in your XAML file?

Comment: What's that?
How do i reference it in my circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946869/is-it-possible-to-share-a-resourcedictionary-file-between-multiple-projects/947042#947042):

> ... as long as Project B has a reference to Project A.
>
> ```
> <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
>     <ResourceDictionary Source="/Project A;component/YourSubFolder/YourResourceFile.xaml" />
> </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
> ```
>
> Then you can just use the Resources defined in YourResourceFile.xaml.