# Accessing resources in Xaml across projects/dlls

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

Is it possible to reference Xaml assets stored in a ResourceDictionary (build action = resource) from another project?  I would like to either merge the assets into the main project's resource dictionary or access them individual.  For example:

- Project "MyResources" contains a folder named "Assets" which has a ResourceDictionary called "MyAssets.xaml" which contains a Style called "ButtonStyle"
- Project "MainProject" references MyResources; in MainWindow.xaml

In MainWindow.xaml I'd like to do something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedResources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyResources/Assets/MyAssets.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedResources>
```

Or, if that's not possible, perhaps:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource /MyResources/Assets/MyAssets.xaml}"/>
```

Is there a way to refer to stuff in MyResources from MainProject?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to 
[ResourceDictionary in a separate assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/wpf-resource-dictionary-in-a-separate-assembly)

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedResources>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component/Subfolder/YourResourceFile.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedResources>
```

Comment: Thank you, my search should have turned that up.  This is a dupe.

Answer (score 15):

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Commons;component/Themes/TreeStyle.xaml" />
```

Where:

**Commons** is the name of the external project

**/Themes/TreeStyle.xaml** corresponds to the location of the style file in project Commons

**;component** is always required

Comment: Thanks for explaining EACH PIECE of the puzzle... +1

Comment: And ensure there's no space between `;` and `component`

Answer (score 4):

You can merge the resources from your project into your main dictionary using this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads a resource dictionary from a URI and merges it into the application resources.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="resourceLocater">URI of resource dictionary</param>
public static void MergeResourceDictionary(Uri resourceLocater)
{
    if (Application.Current != null)
    {
        var dictionary = (ResourceDictionary) Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
MergeResourceDictionary(new Uri(@"/MyOtherAssembly;component/MyOtherResourceDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a code based answer as well, if I could have marked a second answer I would have!