# How to bind to a resource in another project's properties in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to bind a list in xaml as an itemsource. The catch is, the list is kept in a resource file within another project's properties (in the same solution). I've been trying to create a namespace but it continues to tell me that myproject.Properties.Resources does not exist when it clearly does.

Short example to help explain the rough idea:
Project1.xaml

```
<Grid ItemsSource={Binding (binding goes here)} />
```

Project2.Properties.Resources

```
public static namespace.listobject MyList;
```

Hopefully it's relatively straightforward and someone can give me an answer soon. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you search this up? Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1652189/1698987) works for you ?

Comment: I had a search around. I didn't see that before but that still doesn't work.

Comment: do you get the same error ? (and out of curiosity, did you try rebuilding your solution?)

Comment: Yeah, the same error. I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution several times. It's the properties of the project; they always exist.

Comment: I can get it to the project but it doesn't want to find the properties within the project.

Comment: so it's not a general resource, it's the project`s properties one that gives you grief?

Comment: yes. I probably worded the question really wrong to signify that. I'll fix that now

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing another project's settings file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548476/accessing-another-projects-settings-file)

Comment: have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2548476/1698987). I believe it should work :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. It works now (well, at least that bit. Onto the next problem...) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you defined the Ressource over the <kbd>SolutionExplorer</kbd> -> <kbd>Properties</kbd> -> <kbd>Resspource</kbd> -> <kbd>AddRessource</kbd>, then you should have no Problem implementing this solution:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="Image1" UriSource="Resources/yourimage.bmp" />
    </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
       <Image  Source="{StaticResource Image1}"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Don't forget to set the `Build Action` Property of the Image file to `Ressource`.