# Set resource or style to a window from different class library

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism

I am following prism to build wpf application. In my application, there is a helper class library where I defined resources and styles which is going to be used by multiple class libraries in the solution.

But I am getting error when I try to set a resource to Style attribute of a window. The window is in differnt class library as of a resource.

The error that I am getting is :
Cannot find resource named '{resourceName}'. Resource names are case sensitive.  Error at object 'MyWindow' in markup file

I used the following code but it is not working

```
<Window x:Class="Class1" Style="{StaticResource resourceName}">

<Window.Resources>    
        <ResourceDictionary>     
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

       <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/classlibrary;component/Dictionary/resource1.xaml" />              </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    < /ResourceDictionary>

< /Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Comment: your code seems to be trimmed off. Edit and if possible put the complete xaml.

Comment: whoever downvoted the question, please let the questioner (he seems to be new to stackoverflow) know why.

Comment: Why don't you also post the error you're getting - it will help people to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pack URL to get a resource dictionary from another assembly. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/wpf-resource-dictionary-in-a-separate-assembly).

Here is an example of a resource dictionary read from a `Common` assembly:

```
<Application.Resources> 
    <ResourceDictionary> 
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Common;component/styles.xaml"/> 
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
    </ResourceDictionary> 
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [DynamicResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942.aspx) markup extension. The reason for this is because the external ResourceDictionary you import is declared in your xaml after the style is set for your Window. A working example of setting a Window's style with a style defined in a referenced class library is below:

The "MainWindow" xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Style="{DynamicResource TestStyle}">
<Window.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourceDictionary 
Source="pack://application:,,,/ClassLibrary1;component/Styles.xaml">
</ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The ResourceDictionary (defined in a file named Styles.xaml) in a class library:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"></SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, if you don't want the style to be globally available in your application. +1