# Applying global styles to inherited Windows controls in control library

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styles

I'm a complete n00b to WPF but I'm working on my first application. I already realize that styles I use in the application I will likely want to use in future applications, so I'd like to use some method of applying global styles from project to project.

I've seen plenty of tutorials on creating a control library project, but they all go into creating custom controls. I don't really need custom controls (yet) per se, just the standard Windows controls with custom styles.

I'm also a little unclear on the whole ResourceDictionary thing. I've found examples on creating one for an application project, but not so much for a control library project.

What I'm looking for here is a) is a control library really what I need or am I creating more work than necessary? b) am I on the right path with a ResourceDictionary? and c) any good links to tutorials/examples that might go into what I'm trying to do rather than just a custom control creation tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely want a ResourceDictionary with styles that you will be using in other apps.  You can then reference it on an application, window, or even control level by including it in the application, window or control resources.

Where you put that resource dictionary isn't that important, though a custom control project is a common place to do so.  It can be anywhere, in any project, and you can reference it with a URI.

Microsoft has a pretty good writeup on resources: [Using Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx).  Here's a decent tutorial on using dictionaries: [Resource Dictionaries](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/09/understanding-wpf-resourcedictionary.html)

Comment: This was a tough call, but this answer edged out with the link to the tutorial. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction with `ResourceDictionary`. Create one for your application in a separate library move all your `Styles` there and refer them using `Pack URI` syntax. Here is a related question: [ResourceDictionary in a separate assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/wpf-resource-dictionary-in-a-separate-assembly)