# Loading merged ResourceDictionary from different assembly fails

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've put all of my application's ResourceDictionaries into a separate assembly and merged them into one ResourceDictionary which I want to include as a resource in my application:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="InputStyles.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="DataGridStyles.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ComboboxStyles.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="CheckboxStyles.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="TabControlStyles.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Declaring resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/StyleAssembly;component/Styles.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Looking at the designer in VS all controls are displayed with the styles from the files but when I try to start the application I'm getting the following error:

> "Cannot locate resource 'inputstyles.xaml'."

The build action is set to 'Page' for all files and the build for both projects succeeds. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try put "pack://application:,,,/StyleAssembly;component/.........." to your Source properties too

Comment: Note that as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083370/why-does-modifying-project-output-directories-cause-ioexception-was-unhandled output path also is an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [build action should be defined as Resource or Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx) if you are willing to do some of the leg work.

> Your resource must be defined as part of the project as a Resource
>   build action. If you include a resource .xaml file in the project as
>   Resource, you do not need to copy the resource file to the output
>   directory, the resource is already included within the compiled
>   application. You can also use Content build action, but you must then
>   copy the files to the output directory and also deploy the resource
>   files in the same path relationship to the executable.

Answer (score 3):

From my observation. Setting the resource dictonary build style to `Resource` can cause bizarre errors further down the road (I suddenly started getting runtime errors `Cannot create X` where X was a user defined type referenced in my resource dictionary).

I recommend leaving the build style at `Page`. From what I've seen this should work just fine.

Comment: I think "Page" means (on WPF) that XAML gets compiled to BAML

Answer (score 2):

More details on [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28VS.85%29.aspx) & [Merged Resource Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx)

Build action should be **Resource**.

Answer (score 1):

> See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647564/4576125) for both cases **when you know** the external
>   `Assembly` structure (file names etc.) and **when you don't know** and  just want to
>   iterate an external `Assembly` for `ResourceDictionary(s)` or
>   `UserControls`.

***`Both XMAL and C# solution.`***

***Update***

***XAML Way: `If you know the URI of the resource in an Assembly, then load it directly. Transform same syntax in XAML`***

```
ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
 dictionary.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfControlLibrary1;Component/RD1.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
 foreach (var item in dictionary.Values)
 {
    //operations
 }
```

***C# Way: `If you only know the Assambly and don't know the Resources in it`***

```
public ResourceDictionary GetResourceDictionary(string assemblyName)
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
    Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName().Name + ".g.resources");            
    using (ResourceReader reader = new ResourceReader(stream))
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
        {
            var readStream = entry.Value as Stream;
            Baml2006Reader bamlReader = new Baml2006Reader(readStream);
            var loadedObject = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(bamlReader);
            if (loadedObject is ResourceDictionary)
            {
                return loadedObject as ResourceDictionary;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```