# ResourceDictionary not found in editor, works at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

In my WPF application, I'm trying to load a Resource Dictionary from an external assembly.

It's underlined in the designer with a message "An error occured while locating ..." (my message is in french, so not sure about the exact english version).

Here is what I have in my App.xaml :

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MYNAMESPACE;component/Themes/MYFILE.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MYNAMESPACE;component/Styles/MYFILE.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

The two lines that are with MYNAMESPACE get underlined with the messages. I left the Mahapps ones because they work fine and don't get underlined. I redacted the names because they're related to my company.

I found some stuff here saying that the xaml build action should be "Resource" ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475674/loading-merged-resourcedictionary-from-different-assembly-fails)), but someone is saying this can cause problems. The xaml files in Mahapps are "Page" (mine too) and work just fine.

My assembly is a project of type "User Control Library".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember struggling with this same issue. I can't remember what exactly solved my problem, but here is the way I set it up.

The **Build Action** of the resource dictionaries (xaml) is set to `Page`. So I'm quite certain that your assumption was correct.

The project containing the external resource dictionaries is part of the **same solution** I'm working in. So I reference to the dictionaries as followed:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MY.NAMESPACE;component/MyExternalDictionary.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MY.NAMESPACE;component/MYFILE.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyInternalDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This seems to work for me now, but I can't remember if this was all I did to solve it.
 
So if this still doesn't work it could also be caused by a *missing reference*. If one of your external resource dictionaries references something, this might have to be added to your current project as well.

Comment: I wrote it like you, without the "pack..." and also switched between DEBUG and RELEASE and for some reason it fixed it. I had restarted my project before (without fixing it) so I have no idea what happened !