# wpf: setting of ItemsContainerStyle rewrites all custom style of custom TreeViewControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, custom-controls

I developed custom `TreeView` (call it `MyTree`). In `ResourceDictionary` in `General.xaml` of this custom control I defined style for `TreeViewItem` where set control template, that I needed to display every item. First I create special ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="MyTreeViewItem">
.........
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then I use it in custom style for `MyTree`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTree}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTree}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItem}" />
                    </Style>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                ..........
                <ItemsPresenter />
                ..........
             </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Everything works, while i use my control like:

```
<local:MyTree>
     <local:MyTree.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding DependentSuites}"/>
     </local:MyTree.ItemTemplate>
     ..........other property specific for MyTree control.............
</local:MyTree>
enter code here
```

And it does wrong when I try to add style for my TreeViewItem. For example, following code

```
<local:MyTree>
     <local:MyTree.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding DependentSuites}"/>
     </local:MyTree.ItemTemplate>
     ..........other property specific for MyTree control.............
     <local:MultiColumnTreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem"
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </local:MultiColumnTreeView.Resources>
</local:MyTree>
```

cause wpf resets my custom template and start using default style for TreeViewItem. The same situation takes a place if I set any value for ItemsContainerStyle. Other words, any style modification rewrite my custom style in General.xaml. Why does it happen, and how to avoid that, combining all styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just Base it on whatever existing style you want and only modify the stuff necessary for the instance like you're doing using the `Style` [BasedOn Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) like;

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource YourExistingStyleYouWantToBaseItOn}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: I had some thoughts about that decision. But is there way to import styles from DictionarySource which was defined in `Themes/generic.xaml` for custom control in separated CustomControls.dll

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, you mean like using MergedDictionaries?

Comment: Or do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/resourcedictionary-in-a-separate-assembly

Comment: Thank. I'll try your suggestion in a while and give feedback after that.