# How to reference an assembly (residing in relative path) using URI pack syntax?

Tags: wpf

I have this kind of the solution folders structure:

C:\TfsBindRoot\MySln\Development\Sources\WpfProj 
C:\TfsBindRoot\MySln\Development\Sources\Resources

Resources project is referenced in WpfProj.

I tried different variants such as

```
 <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,//Resources" />

 //and

 <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/../Resources" />

 //and

 <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,, ../Resources" />
```

But it does not see the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the path you are providing in not in correct format.

The path depends it the resources are in the same package or different package. Since your question does not provide details of your application pack, check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) site for details for the proper format.

**UPDATE**

*Resource file in subfolder of referenced assembly* -> 
"pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml"

*Resource file in versioned referenced assembly* ->
"pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;v1.0.0.0;component/ResourceFile.xaml"

**UPDATE 2**

I tried and it worked. "ResourceLibrary" was the assembly name.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ResourceLibrary;component/Resources/ResourceFile.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

One thing you might be missing is the ResourceFile.xaml where your might have kept all your resources. My ResourceFile.xaml looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Cornsilk"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Resources and application are in different assemlies.

Comment: Just create yourself a solution with resources-dll at the same level as the exe-project and try it.

Comment: Could you please send it to me? sadocbugger@yandex.ru Zip it and change it's extension, because mail filters can cut it off.

Answer (score -2):

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/YourResources.xaml" />
```

YourResources.xaml replace with name of xaml file which contains resources.

Comment: Did you read my post? The ways I tried don't work and I don't know why.

Comment: if yours resources are in WpfProj assembly and under "Resources" folder then described Uri should work just replace YourResources.xaml with one you have under recources folder. After "component" has to be specified relative path to resources xaml file.

Comment: No, they are not. Resources and application which needs them are in different assemlies.

Comment: I have just updated response just replace YourResources.xaml with correct file name if it is in the root in "Resources" project

Comment: It does not see the Resources.dll.