# Cannot find Child Project's ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have 2 projects under the same solution in VS2010. P1 references P2 as a project.

P1 contains a `UserControl` from P2 and this `UserControl` references many dictionaries and converters from P2 itself. Separately, these 2 projects runs well without issues.

The problem is when P1 calls the `UserControl` from P2, an exception pops out stating that **it cannot find the resource key** which is needed for the UserControl.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

This is the referencing (I had stripped all non-relevant data):

[image: Referencing]

This is P1's App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="P1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" >

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Dictionaries/TabControlDictionary.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Dictionaries/ButtonDictionary.xaml"/>                
            and so on....
</Close Everything>
```

This is P2's App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="P2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" >

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Dictionaries/ListBox1Dictionary.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Dictionaries/ListBox2Dictionary.xaml"/>                          
            and so on....
</Close Everything>
```

And this is where P1 creates the UserControl:

```
<Window xmlns:p2="clr-namespace:P2;assembly=P2"
        and other stuff >
    <Grid>
        <p2:myUserControl />
    </Close Everything>
```

Which threw an exception during runtime saying it can't find resource keys. I should also point out that P1 and P2 are in completely different folder and drives on the HDD.

Comment: Post the relevant xaml. It's hard to determine where your error is

Comment: Hi @Mark I have added more information.Thanks for helping!

Comment: I'm kinda new to WPF as well, but I have a feeling that if you create something in the App.xaml of a project, it exists only if you launch this application. Hence the error: you launch P1 but not P2, because P2 is just referenced. BUT I may be completely mistaken. EDIT: [this may be related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/resourcedictionary-in-a-separate-assembly)

Comment: I think you have a problem with the pack uris could you please edit them to `pack://application:,,,/P2;component/Dictionaries/ListBox1Dictionary.xaml` P2 according to your assembly name