# WPF - Apply Style From Another Assembly to User Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, controls, .net-assembly

I have a solution with multiple projects:

- The Application
- The `User Control Library`
- The `Class Library`

I would like to apply a `Style` contained in the `Class Library` to the `User Control` contained in the `User Control Library`. The problem is that I can't reference the `Style` in the App.xaml like I would do with the main application because I'm working with a `User Control Library` and I don't know how let the `User Control` use the `Class Library` `Styles`. I added the `Class Library` reference to the `User Control Library` but when I set the `Style` for a `User Control` I cannot find the `Style` I want. So what is the current way to do it?

Comment: How you are doing it ? Are you using proper pack uri ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Pack URI?

Comment: How u r referencing resource dictionary ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ResourceDictionary in a separate assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/resourcedictionary-in-a-separate-assembly)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following `MarkupExtension`. You just need to add both files to your `class library`.

WpfRdExt/StyleRefExtension.cs

```
public abstract class StyleRefExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    #region Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// Property for specific resource dictionary
    /// </summary>
    protected static ResourceDictionary RD;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Resource key which we want to extract
    /// </summary>
    public string ResourceKey { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Overriding base function which will return key from RD
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceProvider">Not used</param>
    /// <returns>Object from RD</returns>
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return ProvideValue();
    }

    public object ProvideValue()
    {
        if (RD == null)
            throw new Exception(
                @"You should define RD before usage. 
            Please make it in static constructor of extending class!");
        return RD[ResourceKey];
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Implementation as `StyleRefExt.cs`:

```
public class StyleRefExt : StyleRefExtension
{
    #region Constructors

    static StyleRefExt()
    {
        RD = new ResourceDictionary {
                 Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourNamespace;component/Styles/YourStyle1.xaml")};

        RD.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary {
                                      Source = new Uri(
                                          "pack://application:,,,/YourNamespace;component/Styles/YourStyle2.xaml")});
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then you can use your `Resources` marked by `x:Key="YourKey"` from `class library` in your `user control library` like this:

```
<TextBox Style="{YourNamespace:StyleRefExt ResourceKey=YourKey}" />
```

For me this works fine and I use it too.