# How can I access resources from external assembly?

Tags: wpf

I don't seem to be able to access remote resources from an external assembly.

The following line in MainWindow.xaml isn't working, no background color is getting displayed:

```xml
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type res:DummyForSharingResources}, ResourceId=TestBg}}"></StackPanel>
```

I [published a corresponding repository to GitHub](https://github.com/SetTrend/Wpf-ResourceTest) containing my Visual Studio 2019 solution. It contains all the details.

What I did so far

- "Themes/generic.xaml" file created in supplemental assembly (`StylesAndResources`), filled with resources.
- `ThemeInfoAttribute` updated in application assembly to reference `ResourceDictionaryLocation.ExternalAssembly`.
- Dummy class created in `StylesAndResources` in order to be able to have a [`ComponentResourceKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/componentresourcekey-markup-extension) be generated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [ResourceDictionary in a separate assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/resourcedictionary-in-a-separate-assembly)

Comment: I'm aware of the pack UIR syntax, yet the "correct" way for theming, suggested by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview#defining-resources-at-the-theme-level), is to use a ComponentResourceKey. I'm about to give WPF courses where people may ask me how to solve their issues. So, I need to get the above version running.