# How can I have generic.xaml from class library be used with TargetType only?

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I created a WPF class library containing themes which I want to refer to and use in two WPF applications.

This is an example content, taken from my `\Themes\generic.xaml` file in the class library:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Background">
      <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Tan"/>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And this is the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file I added to the class library:

```cs
using System.Windows;

[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly,  //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
                                                //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                                // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly   //where the generic resource dictionary is located
                                                //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                                // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

Nevertheless, my WPF application doesn't use the styles I've defined in the class library.

What am I missing? Why are the styles from my class library not used by my WPF application although the class library project is referenced by my WPF application?

Comment: In order to use resources from a ResourceDictionary in an external assembly, you would add that assmbly to the MergedDictionaries of a ResourceDictionary in your application, e.g. to Application.Resources. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/resourcedictionary-in-a-separate-assembly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ResourceDictionary in a separate assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/resourcedictionary-in-a-separate-assembly)

Comment: Is this necessary when using `\Themes\generic.xaml`? I believed this file is special in being looked up without being explicitly referenced?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b56640c8-ba9e-45c5-8692-3923e96038a9/how-to-change-the-style-for-built-in-wpf-control-in-genericxaml?forum=wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Themes/generic.xaml naming convention is (only) used to lookup the default style(s) for any controls that are defined in the source assembly (or a specific theme assembly depending on the `[ThemeInfo]` attribute).

It's not used to apply styles to other controls or elements such as `Border`, which is defined in `PresentationFramework.dll`.

So to apply your `Style` to `Border` elements in your app, you need to merge the resource dictionary in your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component/Themes/generic.xaml.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```