# How to access a resource dictionary contained in a referenced UWP Class Library?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I'm playing around with the idea of implementing a component library for a UWP app.

One thing I'm struggling with is accessing resources from resource libraries in the component library from within the main application.

Here's the solution layout for my test application:

[image]

So MainPage.Xaml contains an instance of `TemplatedControl` and I want to give the style (`TemplatedControlStyle`) which is contained in the resource dictionary `Dictionary1`.

How would I go about doing it?

I've had a go with the examples from here [ResourceDictionary in a separate assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/resourcedictionary-in-a-separate-assembly) but that question was about WPF rather than UWP and doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which category of [URI schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes) applies to such case but the following pattern should work.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///[library name]/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a project with the same framework as yours. I used and verified the following two methods, and they can access the resource files in the component library.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ComponentLibraryTest.Components/Dictionary1.xaml" />
   
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///ComponentLibraryTest.Components/Dictionary1.xaml" />
```

By the way, don't forget to add "ComponentLibraryTest.Components" into your main project's References.